# Уравнять длину вложенных списков

Tags: python

Имеется список со вложенными списками разной длинны:

```
arr = [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '2', '3', '4']]
```

Помогите пожалуйста справиться с задачей: Нужно все вложенные списки нужно "нарастить" до одной длины, чтобы `len(вложенного списка) == 5`. И на выходе получить такой результат:

```
arr = [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '0'], ['1', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '0', '0']]
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Разбейте задачу на этапы. Сначала  нужно что определить - длину самого длинного или это всегда 5?

Comment: @MBo Да, длинна должна быть всегда 5, и вложенные списки ни когда не бывают длиннее 4.

Comment: В примере получились списки длины шесть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я написал код на Python, но здесь приведу общюю идею:

```py
for элемент in список:
    if длина элемента < 5:
        элемент += '0' * (5 - длина элемента) # в Python: element += ['0'] * (5 - len(element))
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Это именно то что я искал )

Comment: Больше "н" в слове "длина", еще больше! Чем больше, тем длинннеее!

Answer (score 1):

Есть функция [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

arr = [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '2', '3', '4']]

print(list(map(list, zip(*zip_longest(*arr, fillvalue='_')))))
```

Правда, этот код будет дополнять вложенные списки до длинны самого длинного, но в вашем случае работает:

```
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['1', '2', '_', '_', '_'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '_']]
```